# Making the background image full width

Tags: html, image, css, background

I would like to have background image to whole width. I have CSS code as below.

`background: url(../images/img.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
 background-size: auto 100%;`

But with this code image has margin with two sides. I made margin:0 in body tag of course.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following css.

```
 body, html {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .bg { 
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url(../images/img.png);

        /* Full height */
        height: 100%; 

        /* Center and scale the image nicely */
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the background with `50% 50%` which is kinda weird. So what you do is to use `background-size: cover;` and make sure you give `no-repeat`:

```css
body {background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489844097929-c8d5b91c456e?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=998&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=") no-repeat; background-size: cover;}
```